# Powershell Rounding Down with decimal places

Tags: powershell

I am converting some Excel Calculations to Powershell:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((250000.00-0)*5.00%/12,6)
```

This gives a value of `1041.666666`

I have converted it to Powershell:

```
[Math]::Round((250000.00 - 0) * (5.00/100) / 12,6)
```

But this gives a value of `1041.666667`

The problem is that the last number matters and the fact that powershell doesnt round the `7` down to `6`. This causes problems down the line as the final result for the Excel is `1461.59` but for powershell it is `1461.42`

So, what's the best way to get a correct round-down to a certain number of decimal places in Powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Math.Round` rounds to the *nearest* number, not down. You'd have to roll your own version which uses `Floor`, e.g.:

```
function Get-RoundedDown($d, $digits) {
  $scale = [Math]::Pow(10, $digits)
  [Math]::Truncate($d * $scale) / $scale
}

Get-RoundedDown (250000 * .05 / 12) 6
```

Note, though, that in general there is no guarantee that the number you *see* as a result of that actually only has six digits after the decimal point since what we're doing here is not friendly towards binary floating-point numbers. So it may well be that you receive a number like `1441.666600000003` as a result and there's little you can do about that except switching to `decimal`.

Comment: Note that depending on your case you may want `[Math]::Truncate()` instead of `[Math]::Floor()`.  The difference is in how negative numbers are handled. `[Math]::Truncate(-1.5)` is `-1` while `[Math]::Floor(-1.5)` is `-2`.

Comment: @BaconBits: I'd argue that rounding *down* is not the same as *towards zero*. The Excel function is named `ROUNDDOWN` for a reason.

Comment: It works well the only problem is that these commands are part of automation testing and have to be run from a single line cmd command, so they're a bit harder to read now :)

Comment: @TomPowis: Well, you can shorten it considerably if you want: `$r={$s=+("1e$($args[1])"|iex);[Math]::Floor($args[0]*$s)/$s}; &$r (250000 * .05 / 12) 6`. You could also dot-source common functions in the command-line if you want.

Comment: @Joey Yes, but [Excel's ROUNDDOWN explicitly rounds towards zero](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rounddown-function-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53).  `=ROUNDDOWN(-1.5,0)` has a value of `-1`.  In other words, Excel's ROUNDDOWN() function matches Math.Truncate().  Excel's FLOOR() function also matches Math.Truncate().  For Math.Floor(), you need Excel's FLOOR.MATH() function.

Comment: @Joey When i Do `$2 = $r={$s=+("1e$($args[1])"|iex);[Math]::Floor($args[0]*$s)/$s}; &$r (1+(5.00/100)/12) 6 ` It Outputs `1.004166` but when i call the variable `$2` it returns this `$s=+("1e$($args[1])"|iex);[Math]::Floor($args[0]*$s)/$s` do you know why? Its like it returns the method

Comment: @TomPowis, surround the whole thing with `$()` when you're using it as an expression. The `$r=` part is just the function definition; the return value comes from the invocation after that.

Comment: @Joey How would i escape this section `"1e$($args[1])"` as when i run from Command line i get the errors `The term '1e' is not recognized` and `The term '0' is not recognized`. I'm Running it as `Powershell -Command "$r=..."`

Comment: @Tom: -EncodedCommand, or use the longer function definition, even though it's long (the shorter one I gave you is effectively code-golfed and very unreadable unless you know PowerShell well; it's not something I would use in production that way), or, as noted, dot-sourcing another PowerShell file that contains the function definition. Quoting in CMD is hell already. Build automation tools tend to add another layer of horribleness to the point that sometimes you cannot even quote something correctly.